# why is this share point api filter url malformed

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I am trying to make a request to the share point api filtering on a custom field the url looks like this but the api returns the request is malformed

```
https://bgsquare.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('testLibrary')/items?$select=*,FileRef,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=testColom eq 'Wales'&$expand=File
```

The URL looks correctly formed to me what am I missing?
The request works fine without the filter component.

Comment: What's your result looks like? as it works in my environment.

Comment: I'm interacting with sharepoint through phpSPO library.

this is the response
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: Does the URL works in browser? try to encode the URL and check. testColom eq 'Wales' to be testColom%20eq%20%27Wales%27

Comment: It does appear to work in browser

Comment: You got me in the right direction, it was how url_encode was encoding

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue got solved, so I add the solution as answer.

Encode the URLtestColom eq 'Wales' to be testColom%20eq%20%27Wales%27